# How to set days, time and duration in iCalendar?

Tags: icalendar

I have this event:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//bashmoblie v0.1//NONSGML iCal Writer//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20120830T100000
DTEND:20121212T112000
DTSTAMP:20091130T213238Z
     UID:1285935469767a7c7c1a9b3f0df8003a@yoursever.com
     CREATED:20091130T213238Z
SUMMARY:Class: SOC 104  1 Lecture(1320)
LAST-MODIFIED:20091130T213238Z
     EQUENCE:0
     STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Class: SOC 104  1 Lecture(1320)
LOCATION:Title:  American Race Relations(Lecture)
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

It works successfully with the date range and time 08/30/2012 - 12/12/2012 and 10:00AM - 11:20AM.

My actual requirement is to set this event only for Tuesday and Thursday in the data range 08/30/2012 - 12/12/2012. Now it adds it every day for all day. Can I put in the days and time and duration correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to add recurrence rule (RRULE) to your file. For more details, you can take a look at this [RRULE](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/rrule.html).